# About rails activating post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i want to ask about activating selected post as representative post

what if i have two model

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
end
```

---

and each model has following columns

```
create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t| 
  t.string "title"
  t.boolean "main_post_yn"
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t| 
  t.string "title"
  t.integer "blog_id"
end
```

---

and if user enter main_post_yn as true, i want to show selected single post.

---

so i thought...

```
create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t| 
  t.string "title"
  t.boolean "main_post_yn"
  t.integer "post_id"
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t| 
  t.string "title"
  t.integer "blog_id"
end
```

i add post_id to blog model.

---

and i though following flow.

1. user click "main_post_yn" true.
2. show all posts which belongs to blog.
3. user select single post and pass it's id to Blog.post_id
4. at main page, pass "Post.id = Blog.post_id" in controller and show it as representative post

---

i think upper process isn't rails way. 
do you have any advise?

thanks.

Comment: To make sure I get you right - you have many blogs and each of the has many posts. You want user to pick a post from one of the blogs and show it in the homepage for that user? If so you should add that `post_id` to your users table. And thats pretty much it. Your user gets a selected post_id in his db table and you can use it where ever you want..

Comment: you need any relation between your `user` and `post`, or all users can see the `posts`, whose blog's `main_post_yn` is true?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `Blog has_many :posts` and `Post belongs_to :blog`

Don't, add `post_id` in `Blog table`.

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
end


create_table "blogs", force: :cascade do |t| 
  t.string "title"
  t.boolean "main_post_yn"
end

create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t| 
  t.string "title"
  t.integer "blog_id"
end
```

Now, In the controller,

```
blogs = Blog.where(main_post_yn: true) // get all blogs with `main_post_yn` as true

@post_ids = []

blogs.each do |blog|
    @post_ids << blog.posts.pluck(:id) // push post-Id's of those blogs into an array
end

@posts = Post.where(id: @post_ids) // get all posts with those post-Id's
```

**show all posts which belongs to blog**. got fulfilled.

Comment: @lee, please check my answer